# Ignoring special characters in search query

Tags: mysql, escaping

I've been wracking my brain trying to find a solution for this for a couple of days.   I'm trying to make a "smart" query that can handle a wide range of  search terms.      The queries run fine until there are special characters involved and I've had some success w/ the REPLACE method on some characters such as commas and dashes.   Other characters such as quotes and ampersands will result in empty queries.

Here's a few examples:

the original name I'm searching for is "French Is Fun, Book 1 - 1 Year Option" and with this query below, I get results returned with these search terms:

```
1.  "French Is Fun"
2.  "French Is Fun, book"
3.  "French Is Fun, book"
4.  "French Is Fun, Book 1"


SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE ( (LOWER(name) LIKE '%french is fun book%' OR
LOWER(replace(name, '  ','')) LIKE '%french is fun book%' OR
LOWER(replace(name, ' ','')) LIKE '%french is fun book%' OR
LOWER(replace(name, '-','')) LIKE '%french is fun book%')
```

However, when the original title has an ampersand in it like such: "Global History & Geography: The Growth of Civilizations - 1 Year Option" - I get an empty query when I try these different search terms:

```
1.  "Global History & Geography"
2.  "Global History Geography"
```

I've tried this to no avail

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE  
(LOWER(name) LIKE '%global history geograph%' OR  
    LOWER(replace(name, '  ','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR  
    LOWER(replace(name, ' ','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR 
    LOWER(replace(name, ',','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR 
    LOWER(replace(name, '&','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR  
    LOWER(replace(name, '-','')) LIKE '%global history geography%');
```

I also tried adding an escape character to the ampersand and it doesn't help:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE  
(LOWER(name) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR  
    LOWER(replace(name, '  ','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR  
    LOWER(replace(name, ' ','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR 
    LOWER(replace(name, ',','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR 
    LOWER(replace(name, '\&','')) LIKE '%global history geography%' OR  
    LOWER(replace(name, '-','')) LIKE '%global history geography%');
```

And commas in the name also return empty results.    As a demonstration, the original name is this:

"Amsco's AP Calculus AB/BC Preparing for the Advanced Placement Examinations - 1 Year Option"

This attempt always returns empty queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE 
( (LOWER(name) LIKE '%amscos ap calculus%' OR
     LOWER(replace(name, ' ','')) LIKE '%amscos ap calculus%' OR
     LOWER(replace(name, '\'','')) LIKE '%amscos ap calculus%' OR
     LOWER(replace(name, ',','')) LIKE '%amscos ap calculus%' OR
     LOWER(replace(name, '-','')) LIKE '%amscos ap calculus%')
    ) AND ( (`products`.`type` = 'Rental' ) );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me, that your whole approach is not that good. What about searching for "Global Geography & History"? You better should split up your query and utilize a full-text search, e.g. using `MATCH() … AGAINST …`

Answer (score 3):

The way you're going you're going to have your DB server doing the same work over and over until it dies of resource exhaustion.

**Short Version:**

Add another column to the table that contains the title already stripped of special chars and lower-cased. Select based on that.

**Medium Version:**

Use [Full-Text Indexing/Searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

**Long Version**

Create a separate table structure that tracks individual words and their associations to various titles and create queries/program logic to search with it.

Comment: The short version might work, the medium version is a no-go since we're using mysql 5.5 and aren't going to upgrade, and the long version would be too much work in the time frame I've been allotted.   So, looking into the short version now.

Comment: Uhh... fulltext has been available since somewhere in v3 IIRC. The only requirement is that the table type is myISAM.

Comment: yeah - I already looked into the idea of changing table type to myISAM and there's noway we're going to do that.

Comment: You could create a separate, fulltext-indexed myISAM table with just the title and a key pointing back to `products`. It's a little more administrative work to keep it in sync with the innoDB tables, but fulltext is pretty nice.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do this Way:

```
SELECT part_no, nomenclature FROM store_info WHERE 
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(part_no,'/',''),'-',''),'.',''
) LIKE '%LWR0492%'
```